# window singleton

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Greetings, 
In our application user may click on item in datagrid and new window with list of companies is shown based on that item. Client wants this window to be non modal and if window is already opened and user clicks on different item in datagrid this window will be reloaded with new data from item in datagrid. How can we achieve it? application is written in wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a candidate for [M-V-VM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) to me.  Fortunatly, WPF lends itself quite well to this pattern

Where the datagrid binds to a data source on your model and your data in the new window binds to a View of the data on the same model and therefore, since you are using DependencyProperties or INotifyPropertyChanged on your model object, the data in the window will update automagically.